# Chaincode Install ERROR from client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying install fabcar-chaincode from client.

[In line with](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) I have started Fabric-v1.0 and created channel, 
and then ran enrollAdmin.js and registerUser.js.

I would like to install fabcar using installchaincode.js I have created.

But following error occurred.

```
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Authorization for INSTALL has been denied (error-Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]))
Failed to install proposal :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

Can someone help me how to install chaincode from client.

My code is this.

```js
'use strict';
/*
* Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
*
* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
/*
 * Chaincode query
 */

var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var os = require('os');

var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

// setup the fabric network
var channel = fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel');
var targets = [];
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:7051');
targets.push(peer);
var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store');
console.log('Store path:'+store_path);
var tx_id = null;

// create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
}).then((state_store) => {
 // assign the store to the fabric client
 fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
 var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
 // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
 // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
 var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
 crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
 fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

 // get the enrolled user from persistence, this user will sign all requests
 return fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
 if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
  console.log('Successfully loaded admin from persistence');
  member_user = user_from_store;
 } else {
  throw new Error('Failed to enroll admin.... run enrollAdmin.js');
 }

 process.env.GOPATH = '/Users/testuser/gopath';
 // send proposal to endoser
 var request = {
  targets: targets,
  chaincodePath: 'github.com/fabcar',
  chaincodeId : 'fabcar',
  chaincodeVersion : '1.0'
 }
 // send the query proposal to the peer
 return fabric_client.installChaincode(request);
}).then((result) => {
 console.log("install request has completed, checking results");
 // query_responses could have more than one  results if there multiple peers were used as targets
 var proposal_response = result;
 if (proposal_response && proposal_response.response.status === 200) {
   console.log("install proposal was good");
 } else {
  console.log("install proposal was bad");
 }
}).catch((err) => {
 console.error('Failed to install proposal :: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest posting a code sample.  Might help us figure out where the error in your code is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I posted my code.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code ... it is pretty much what I expected.  Last question - are you using one of the sample compose files to bring up your peer(s)?

Comment: I'm using fabcar-sample as it is. 1peer,1orderer,1ca,1couchdb and 1cli.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The installation users to be loaded were different.

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you solve it? I am also having same issue.

Comment: when i tried this, get an error : Path must be a string. Received undefined. how can i solve this?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. could you help me to solve this?